# Actualización de tablas de interfaz de usuario en varios clientes

Tags: python, mysql

Estoy realizando una aplicación de gestión de datos con Python y MySQL altas bajas y modificaciones, pero quiero montar esta aplicación en varias computadoras sobre una misma red, ya hice que cada computadora pueda conectarse y acceda a los datos, pero al momento de realizar una inserción desde un cliente los demás no se cómo hacer para que se actualicen sus interfaces y así todos estén al mismo tiempo con la información actualizada

Eh intentado con websockets y con hilos en un bucle infinito que consulte a la base de datos, pero se me hace una opción no muy buena, y los websockets no se implementarlo muy bien

Answer (score 0):

WebSockets o polling. Con websockets hay un poco más de truco, porque tendrías que tener un proceso separado al que se queden conectados los clientes, y cuando se haga una actualización de datos, informar a ese proceso para que notifique a los clientes. Por así decirlo, habría un proceso API y otro "Streaming", y cuando hay cambios relevantes en API, este llama a `Streaming` para informar de los cambios, y este luego manda mensajes por el socket.

Mediante Polling, podrías mantener en alguna base de datos (ya sea una tabla SQL o algo especializado como Redis) un registro de cambios a cada entidad. El cliente hace una petición a una ruta para obtener datos, indicando la última modificación con la cabecera `If-Modified-Since`, y el servidor comprueba contra la base de datos la fecha de cambio, y devuelve `304 (Not Modified)` si siguen siendo datos actuales, y `200 OK` con los nuevos datos si cambiaron.

Por ejemplo, el flujo sería tal que:

1. Cliente1 carga los datos de `Libro` a las `12:00`
2. Cada N segundos, Cliente1 consulta al servidor "¿Ha habido cambios a Libro desde las 12:00?"

```http
GET /Libros HTTP/1.1
Host: example.com
If-Modified-Since: Wed, 22 Feb 2024 12:00:00 GMT
```

3. El servidor comprueba la caché, y ve que `Libro => 11:30`, anterior a la fecha que pregunta el cliente. Por tanto, devuelve un 304 sin contenido.

```http
HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified
Last-Modified: Wed, 22 Feb 2024 11:30:00 GMT
```

4. Usuario2 hace una modificación a `Libro` a las 12:05. El servidor actualiza la caché para reflejarlo: `Libro => 12:05`.
5. Usuario1 vuelve a consultar si hubo cambios, como en el punto 2. El servidor, en este caso ve que sí hubo cambios, y responde acorde:

```http
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Last-Modified: Wed, 22 Feb 2024 12:05:00 GMT
Content-Type: application/json

[
    { ... }
]
```

Evidentemente, esto se puede sofisticar en sistemas más complejos, ya sea guardando otros datos como la "página" de datos y otras cosas; pero la esencia sería la misma. Y con WebSockets es la opción más recomendable.